# Cherrypy URLs with unknown application mount path

Tags: python-2.7, url-routing, cherrypy

I have a CherryPy webapp that is hosted by the user. Typically the main application is mounted as such:

```
cherrypy.tree.mount(root,
                    '/',
                    root.conf
                    )
```

However, in order to have it work behind a reverse proxy such as nginx, it needs to be able to mount elsewhere, to whatever path the user chooses:

```
mount = '/my_application'
cherrypy.tree.mount(root,
                    mount,
                    root.conf
                    )
```

Where mount can be anything the user chooses.

The problem now is that links become broken.

```
raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect("/news")
```

No longer works. It will redirect to address:port/news when I need to redirect to address:port/my_application/news.

I could go through and create a conditional for each url that prepends the application path:

```
if mount != '/':
    url = mount + '/news'
raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect(url)
```

But there must be a better way to do this. I've looked at Request Dispatching but I couldn't get it to re-write urls on the fly.

What is the best way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the helper function `cherrypy.url` to generate the urls relative to the `script_name` (`/my_application`).

You will end up with something like:

```
raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect(cherrypy.url('/news'))
```

Link for the `cherrypy.url` source: https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/blob/master/cherrypy/_helper.py#L194

Comment: yeah I was hoping I wouldn't have to go through all of my templates and js scripts to modify each url, but it looks like that is the only way.

Comment: Won't let me edit, but thanks for the pointers. Much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, as far as I know, that's the only way.

Comment: I wrote an ugly implementation of `url_for`, which is trying to collect all the URL in the app and provide resolving of them. The challenge here is that there may be lots of custom dispatchers doing insane URI conversions.